# How to remove link to Lookup field in default DispForm

Tags: lookup-column, hyperlink, display-form, default

I have a list, with several fields, including a Lookup field. I display the items of the list on a custom webpart. Everything works fine. When I click on an item in the web part, the default DispForm is displayed with all the fields with values. The lookup field is displayed as a link to the original item to another list, ie there is a link I can click, but I do not want the end user can do this. I don't want to display the lookup value as link?

How it can be done?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use substrings to extract and display the text of the hyperlink:

```
<_remove_ xsl:variable name="overallstatussegment">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@OverallStatus, '&gt;')" />
<_remove_/xsl:variable>
<_remove_xsl:value-of select="substring-before($overallstatussegment, '&lt;')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer led me in the right direction but I had to clean up the XSL code a bit and added a few more substrings to get this to work for me (SP 2010):

```
<xsl:variable name="DivisionUrl">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Division,'&quot;&gt;')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DivisionUrl,'&lt;/a&gt;')"/>
```

Display form entire table row example:

```
 <tr>
  <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
   <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Division</nobr>
   </H3>
  </td>
  <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
   <xsl:variable name="DivisionUrl">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Division,'&quot;&gt;')"/>
   </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DivisionUrl,'&lt;/a&gt;')"/>       
  </td>
 </tr>
```